# Integração pelo método de Simpson no R

Tags: r, integração

Eu tenho os dados do campo elétrico em uma matriz, deste dados eu preciso utilizar o método de [Simpson](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Simpson) neste **E**.

No MATLAB, eu já consigo.

Alguém sabe algum pacote ou função built in do R que faça isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente a função `sintegral` do pacote [Bolstad2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Bolstad2/).

Exemplo do [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Bolstad2/Bolstad2.pdf):

```
## integrate the normal density from -3 to 3
x<-seq(-3,3,length=100)
fx<-dnorm(x)
estimate<-sintegral(x,fx)$int
true.val<-diff(pnorm(c(-3,3)))
cat(paste("Absolute error :",round(abs(estimate-true.val),7),"\n"))
cat(paste("Relative percentage error :", 100*round((abs(estimate-true.val)/true.val),6),"%\n"))
```